# Load balancing hiveserver2 in hadoop minicluster using zookeeper

Tags: unit-testing, hadoop, hive, load-balancing, apache-zookeeper

We have a significant number of hive unit tests which runs in hadoop minicluster. The issue is that they run in sequence and takes about an hour to complete for each build. We would like to parallelize hive unit tests by using multiple hive server2 load balanced with zookeeper.

When connecting directly to the hiveserver2 instance with connection string "**jdbc:hive2://localhost:20103/default**", it works as expected. However, when connecting to zookeeper using connection string "**jdbc:hive2://localhost:22010/default;serviceDiscoveryMode=zooKeeper;zooKeeperNamespace=hiveserver2**", it fails with the following error.

Is the zookeeper in hadoop minicluster capable of doing load balancing?

```
INFO: Connecting to : jdbc:hive2://localhost:22010/default;serviceDiscoveryMode=zooKeeper;zooKeeperNamespace=hiveserver2

java.sql.SQLException: org.apache.hive.jdbc.ZooKeeperHiveClientException: Unable to read HiveServer2 configs from ZooKeeper

    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:135)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:105)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: org.apache.hive.jdbc.ZooKeeperHiveClientException: Unable to read HiveServer2 configs from ZooKeeper
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.ZooKeeperHiveClientHelper.configureConnParams(ZooKeeperHiveClientHelper.java:80)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils.configureConnParams(Utils.java:505)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils.parseURL(Utils.java:425)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:133)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoNodeException: KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /hiveserver2
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:111)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.getChildren(ZooKeeper.java:1590)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetChildrenBuilderImpl$3.call(GetChildrenBuilderImpl.java:214)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetChildrenBuilderImpl$3.call(GetChildrenBuilderImpl.java:203)
    at org.apache.curator.RetryLoop.callWithRetry(RetryLoop.java:107)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetChildrenBuilderImpl.pathInForeground(GetChildrenBuilderImpl.java:199)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetChildrenBuilderImpl.forPath(GetChildrenBuilderImpl.java:191)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetChildrenBuilderImpl.forPath(GetChildrenBuilderImpl.java:38)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.ZooKeeperHiveClientHelper.configureConnParams(ZooKeeperHiveClientHelper.java:63)
    ... 32 more
```

Versions used

```
<hive.version>1.2.1000.2.4.0.0-169</hive.version>
<hadoop.version>2.7.1.2.4.0.0-169</hadoop.version>
<minicluster.version>0.1.14</minicluster.version>
```

Server Configuration

```
public HiveServerRunner() {

    zookeeperLocalCluster = new ZookeeperLocalCluster.Builder()
      .setPort(22010)
      .setTempDir("embedded_zk")
      .setZookeeperConnectionString("127.0.0.1:22010")
      .setDeleteDataDirectoryOnClose(true)
      .build();

    hiveLocalMetaStore = new HiveLocalMetaStore.Builder()
      .setHiveMetastoreHostname("localhost")
      .setHiveMetastorePort(20102)
      .setHiveMetastoreDerbyDbDir("metastore_db")
      .setHiveScratchDir("hive_scratch_dir")
      .setHiveWarehouseDir("warehouse_dir")
      .setHiveConf(buildHiveConf())
      .build();

    hiveLocalServer2 = new HiveLocalServer2.Builder()
      .setHiveServer2Hostname("localhost")
      .setHiveServer2Port(20103)
      .setHiveMetastoreHostname("localhost")
      .setHiveMetastorePort(20102)
      .setHiveMetastoreDerbyDbDir("metastore_db")
      .setHiveScratchDir("hive_scratch_dir")
      .setHiveWarehouseDir("warehouse_dir")
      .setHiveConf(buildHiveConf())
      .setZookeeperConnectionString("127.0.0.1:22010")
      .build();
}

public static HiveConf buildHiveConf() {
    HiveConf hiveConf = new HiveConf();
    hiveConf.set("hive.txn.manager", "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lockmgr.DbTxnManager");
    hiveConf.set("hive.compactor.initiator.on", "true");
    hiveConf.set("hive.compactor.worker.threads", "5");
    hiveConf.set("hive.root.logger", "DEBUG,console");
    hiveConf.set("hadoop.bin.path", System.getenv("HADOOP_HOME") + "/bin/hadoop");
    hiveConf.set("hive.exec.submit.local.task.via.child", "false");
    hiveConf.set("hive.server2.support.dynamic.service.discovery", "true");
    hiveConf.set("hive.zookeeper.quorum", "127.0.0.1:22010");
    hiveConf.setIntVar("hive.metastore.connect.retries", 3);
    System.setProperty("HADOOP_HOME", WindowsLibsUtils.getHadoopHome());
    return hiveConf;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Zookeeper does do the load balancing, rather it will direct the client's request to the available **random** HS2.

For more details please see the link below

https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.0/bk_hadoop-high-availability/content/ha-hs2-service-discovery.html

Comment: Zookeeper does load balancing, however, the question is about zk in minicluster which is used for running unit tests for the cluster. Doing load balancing in minicluster will enable to run tests in parallel. But, zk doesn't seem to do load balancing in the minicluster.